# Go : can assign struct to an interface, but not superstruct

Tags: inheritance, interface, go

The following Go code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Polygon struct {
    sides int
    area int
}

type Rectangle struct {
    Polygon
    foo int
}

type Shaper interface {
    getSides() int
}

func (r Rectangle) getSides() int {
    return 0
}

func main() {   
    var shape Shaper = new(Rectangle) 
    var poly *Polygon = new(Rectangle)  
}
```

causes this error:

```
cannot use new(Rectangle) (type *Rectangle) as type *Polygon in assignment
```

I can't assign a Rectangle instance to a Polygon reference, like I can in Java. What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: What language is it? Not Java for sure.

Comment: Removing "Java" tag. Please tag the question with correct language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're thinking of the ability to embed structs in other structs as inheritance, which it is not. Go is not object-oriented, and it doesn't have any concept of classes or inheritance. The embedded struct syntax is just a nice shorthand that allows for some syntactic sugar. The Java equivalent of your code is more closely:

```java
class Polygon {
    int sides, area;
}

class Rectangle {
    Polygon p;
    int foo;
}
```

I assume you were imagining that it was equivalent to:

```java
class Polygon {
    int sides, area;
}

class Rectangle extends Polygon {
    int foo;
}
```

which is not the case.

Comment: so Go only supports "has-a" relationships, and not "is-a" relationships?

Comment: I suppose you could put it that way, although most people frame it in those terms. Go supports structs with fields, and those fields can be anything which is a valid type, and since structs are valid types, those fields can be structs. The "call methods directly on the containing struct" pattern is just a convenience, not a real language feature.

Comment: Yep, np! If you're familiar with C, Go structs are much closer to C structs than Java classes.